# AIMA, Mutation in Genetic Algorithm

Tags: genetic-algorithms, norvig-russell

[image]

With regards to the highlighted line, the authors earlier stated that:

> The mutation rate, which determines how often offspring have random mutations to
> their representation. Once an offspring has been generated, every bit in its composition
> is flipped with probability equal to the mutation rate.

Doesn't this contradict the highlighted line in the code? Because according to this quote we mutate the children with the small probability called mutation rate every time they are generated so the actual code in my opinion should be:

```
for each bit in child string
    if (small random probability >= mutation rate) mutate bit
```

instead of:

```
 if (small random probability) mutate(child)
```

Comment: Please don't upload code as images, use > . Images are not searchable for the text that they contain. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

GAs are really a framework around a bunch of closely related ideas that can be tweaked in slightly different ways, and there's no good way to know what the authors intended aside from asking them or maybe finding an errata listing somewhere.

That said, I think your assumption is correct. I think the pseudocode is probably not saying exactly what they intended it to say, and the textual description is the correct one.

Generally, we'd implement this as

```
child <- REPRODUCE(parent1, parent2)
for each bit in child
    if random() < mutation rate
        flip bit
```

as you suspected.

Comment: Agree. Also, a good place to check what is "standard practice" is the [microbial GA](https://users.sussex.ac.uk/~inmanh/MicrobialGA_ECAL2009.pdf), which agrees with this too.